# Visual Studio Code still displaying the characters while typing even with var_prompt set to private:yes in Ansible

Tags: visual-studio-code, ansible

I have noticed this strange behavior and I am not able to figure out why? It displays whatever I am typing in the prompt and immediately hides it but `private:yes` setting is supposed to hide the typed characters as well.

Setup in my playbook:

```
---

- hosts: all
  gather_facts: no
  vars_prompt:
    - name: ticket
      prompt: "Enter ticket number"
      private: yes
```

Answer (score 3):

> I have noticed this strange behavior and I am not able to figure out why?

Likely because the [terminal emulator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminal_emulator) that is built into VS code does not honor the [stty -echo](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/en/man1/stty.1.html) setting correctly. That terminal emulator is just designed for your convenience, and not 100% accuracy with every terminal emulator standard

Feel free to open an issue with VS code describing your experience